# Is there a way to check if page was reloaded with WebDriver (java)?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify an element after every update.Ex: Lowrtemperature:7.54 after some time the value changes to Lowrtemperature:3.78 ,5.87,9.32 ...etchere the value is changing after some time(time varies) each time. but i need the driver to get the updated value afterthe change .how to get the element using selenium webdriver

```
WebElement PrecipitationLabel_14_L= (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='webFor']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]")));
String Precipationclass= PrecipitationLabel_14_L.getAttribute("class");
return Precipationclass;
```

Comment: Can you consider updating us the exact requirement? Do you want to compare the different values of "Lowrtemperature" among "7.54" & "3.78". Please consider updating the relevant HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: I no need to compare the values,once it gets updated then I need the  driver should get the updated value ,so driver should take the xpath value after update

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of your test should be to ensure that the text is updated.
Whether the page is reloaded or not should be irrelevant here.

Here's an example waiting for the text to be updated:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

String temperatureBefore = wait.until(textToBeDifferent(By.cssSelector(...), ""));
String temperatureAfter = wait.until(textToBeDifferent(By.cssSelector(...), temperatureBefore));
```

And the custom waiter:

```java
public static ExpectedCondition<String> textToBeDifferent(final By locator, final String text) {
  return new ExpectedCondition<String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(WebDriver driver) {
      try {
        String elemText = driver.findElement(locator).getText().trim();
        return elemText.equals(text) ? null : elemText;
      } catch (NoSuchElementException  e) {
        return null;
      } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("text ('%s') to not be found by %s", text, locator);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if it was updated with the same value as the original

Comment: @Corey Goldberg, are you sure about that? I'd say that from an end-user perspective, the page is not updated if the value he sees remains the same. The context here is end to end testing, where tests are focused on user interaction and not technical behavior.

Comment: @FlorentB. Does'nt the combination of ExpectedConditions of not() and textToBe() accomplish the same thing? ExpectedConditions.not( ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By... , initialTemp))....

Comment: @Grasshopper, the `not` returns a `Boolean` from `.until`. It doesn't return the result from the expected condition.

Comment: @FlorentB. i need to ensure that the text is updated

Comment: @FlorentB,what should i add in the " " in the given lines of code,the Lowertemperature value varies each time i can not take any fixed text before   String temperatureBefore =wait.until(textToBeDifferent(By.cssSelector(...), "")); in http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/  in the given link u can see that the values varies each time in ascending and descending order also , i want to verify the similar that Note:update generally will take maximum two minutes